# Path messed up for theme assets in Wordpress on RedHat OpenShift

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift

I've installed Wordpress on Openshift (free plan). When I go to 'Theme Options' page, the assets path are getting messed up. It's adding the full server path after `http://sitename.com/wp-content/` as `/var/lib/openshift/54...72a/app-root/data/` resulting in assets paths like this:

`https://sitename.com/wp-content//var/lib/openshift/54...72a/app-root/data/themes/lens/wpgrade-core/vendor/redux3/inc/fields/typography/field_typography.css`.

I am able to install the theme locally just fine, everything loads perfectly. The site itself loads correctly on OpenShift, only the 'Theme Options' page has this issue.

Comment: Is this a custom theme that you wrote? Or that you downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: This is a 5 star (~350 ratings) pro theme I bought from Themeforest. Also, I'm able to install it locally just fine

Comment: Since your application is served from a symlinked directory, that can happen.  I think there is a different wordpress function that needs to be used to get that path, but I'm not sure which one would be appropriate.  Maybe check the default themes it ships with as they seem to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks @developercorey. That seems to be the case. I've contacted the theme's customer support.